# How to use to_sql in pandas

Tags: mysql, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I'm trying to get to the bottom of what I thought would be a simple problem: exporting a dataframe in Pandas into a mysql database.

There is a scraper that collates data in pandas to save the csv format

```
**title, summary, url** #header
  abc,   summary, some_url
```

But I'd like to send the dataframe directly to a mysql database with the same three-column format.

My code so far is:

```
import mysql.connector

# Connect to the database
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='somepassword', host='localhost', port='3306', database='db')

# Write the DataFrame to the database
df.to_sql(name='table_name', con=conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Close the connection
conn.close()
```

But this returns an error message of:

```
pandas.errors.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

How do I fix this?

UPDATE:

I have read that I might have to use sqlalchemy but I really want to stick with pandas' solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use pandas solution, but you have to use `sqlalchemy.create_engine` instead of `mysql.connector.connect`, since `to_sql` expects "`sqlalchemy.engine.(Engine or Connection)` or `sqlite3.Connection`" as `con` argument. See [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) and examples there. This should be working fine:

```python
import sqlalchemy

# Connect to the database
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
'mysql+mysqlconnector://root:somepassword@localhost:3306/db')

# Write the DataFrame to the database
df.to_sql(name='table_name', con=conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Close the connection
conn.close()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not passing a SQLAlchemy connection, then to_sql assumes that you are using a SQLite backend. That is why you are receiving the error shown.

Do you have to use to_sql? You can use the mysql.connector directly. There are some examples in the mysql documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

You could iterate through your dataframe and insert the rows, like this:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='somepassword', host='localhost', port='3306', database='db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (title, summary, url) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Ideally, if you want to do performant inserts using MySQL as the backend storage, use SQLAlchemy. Alternatively, use `load data infile` in MySQL to import the csv directly.